# How to Fix "npm ERR! addLocal Could not install"

Tags: npm, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm getting this error when attempting to push my Phoenix application to Heroku.

I've been following the [guide from the Phoenix framework website](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku).

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

```
WARNING: phoenix_static_buildpack.config wasn't found in the app
remote:        Using default config from Phoenix static buildpack
remote:        Will use the following versions:
remote:        * Node 6.9.2
remote:        Will export the following config vars:
remote:        * Config vars DATABASE_URL
remote:        * MIX_ENV=prod
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        Downloading node 6.9.2...
remote:        Installing Node 6.9.2...
remote:        Using default npm version
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing and caching node modules
remote:        npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /tmp/build_23f60aac277eab15b4ce274dcaf9bb16/deps/phoenix
remote:        npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /tmp/build_23f60aac277eab15b4ce274dcaf9bb16/deps/phoenix_html

remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_23f60aac277eab15b4ce274dcaf9bb16/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_23f60aac277eab15b4ce274dcaf9bb16/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--quiet" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_23f60aac277eab15b4ce274dcaf9bb16/npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v6.9.2
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_23f60aac277eab15b4ce274dcaf9bb16/deps/phoenix
remote:        npm ERR! code ENOENT
remote:        npm ERR! errno -2
remote:        npm ERR! syscall open
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_23f60aac277eab15b4ce274dcaf9bb16/deps/phoenix'
remote:        npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_23f60aac277eab15b4ce274dcaf9bb16/deps/phoenix'
remote:        npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
remote:        npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
remote:        npm ERR! enoent
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_23f60aac277eab15b4ce274dcaf9bb16/npm-debug.log
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Phoenix app.
```

Comment: From the output seems that your node was updated and npm wasn't. Maybe manually update npm? Found the possible solution here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10165#issuecomment-152451743

Comment: I've tried this (found that thread before asking the question) and it doesn't help. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Did you try use sudo?

Comment: Yes, I've run hat command using sudo as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as you before. Try adding the npm version to the phoenix_static_buildpack.config file

Here's a sample from my app:

*phoenix_static_buildpack.config* (in the root)

```
clean_cache=false
compile="compile"
config_vars_to_export=(DATABASE_URL)
node_version=6.9.5
npm=3.10.8
phoenix_relative_path=.
remove_node=false
```

You can also set the
*elixir_buildpack.config* (also in the root directory)

```
erlang_version=18.3
elixir_version=1.4.0
always_rebuild=false
runtime_path=/app
```